# Remove extension when creating a new image from resizing

Tags: php

i have this code, which i kind of modified a little bit ago.. my problem is that this creates a new thumbnail of the image i upload but it adds a .PNG,.JPEG etc etc extension which i don't need! now, my problem is that if i try to remove from the function the extensions it won't let me create the new image...

What i mean is that if i remove : '.'.$this->ext from the createFile function it won't create the file anymore...

Here is the code... it seems to be a little long but it isn't..

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {


function setFile($src = null) {
    $this->ext = strtoupper(pathinfo($src, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

if(is_file($src) && ($this->ext == "JPG" OR $this->ext == "JPEG")) {
        $this->img_r = ImageCreateFromJPEG($src);
    } elseif(is_file($src) && $this->ext == "PNG") {
        $this->img_r = ImageCreateFromPNG($src);
    } elseif(is_file($src) && $this->ext == "GIF") {
        $this->img_r = ImageCreateFromGIF($src);
    }

$this->img_w = imagesx($this->img_r);
    $this->img_h = imagesy($this->img_r);
}

function resize($largestSide = 100) {
    $width = imagesx($this->img_r);
    $height = imagesy($this->img_r);
    $newWidth = 0;
    $newHeight = 0;

    if ($width > $height) {
        $newWidth = $largestSide;
        $newHeight = $height * ($newWidth / $width);
    } else {
        $newHeight = $largestSide;
        $newWidth = $width * ($newHeight / $height);
    }

    $this->dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor($newWidth, $newHeight);
    imagecopyresampled($this->dst_r, $this->img_r, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);
    $this->img_r = $this->dst_r;
    $this->img_h = $newHeight;
    $this->img_w = $newWidth;
}

function createFile($output_filename = null) {
    if ($this->ext == "JPG" OR $this->ext == "JPEG") {
        imageJPEG($this->dst_r, $this->uploaddir.$output_filename.'.'.$this->ext, $this->quality);
    } elseif($this->ext == "PNG") {
        imagePNG($this->dst_r, $this->uploaddir.$output_filename.'.'.$this->ext);
    } elseif($this->ext == "GIF") {
        imageGIF($this->dst_r, $this->uploaddir.$output_filename.'.'.$this->ext);
    }

    $this->output = $this->uploaddir.$output_filename.'.'.$this->ext;
}

function setUploadDir($dirname) {
$this->uploaddir = $dirname;
}

function flush() {
$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
$targetFile = str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

imagedestroy($this->dst_r);
unlink($targetFile);
imagedestroy($this->img_r);

}

}

$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
$targetFile = str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

move_uploaded_file ($tempFile, $targetFile);

$image = new Image();
$image->setFile($targetFile);
$image->setUploadDir($targetPath);
$image->resize(800);
$image->createFile($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
$image->flush();
}
```

Comment: Please don't define functions within an `if` statement. That is a terrible practice, even if it *is* valid PHP.

Comment: BTW you never call any of those functions within the `if` statement; you only define them. That may be why your code isn't working.

Comment: Hey thanks, i'm just modifying it, if i were that capable to build it i wouldn't ask... i mean i understand the logic... but i can't rearrange it the way i need..

Comment: Also, you have an extra close-curly at the end there.

Answer (score 0):

After formatting your code and removing the extra close-curly at the end (while moving your function definitions outside of your `if` statement), your code should look something like this:

```
<?php

function setFile($src = null) {
    $this->ext = strtoupper(pathinfo($src, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    if (is_file($src) && ($this->ext == "JPG" OR $this->ext == "JPEG")) {
        $this->img_r = ImageCreateFromJPEG($src);
    } elseif (is_file($src) && $this->ext == "PNG") {
        $this->img_r = ImageCreateFromPNG($src);
    } elseif (is_file($src) && $this->ext == "GIF") {
        $this->img_r = ImageCreateFromGIF($src);
    }
    $this->img_w = imagesx($this->img_r);
    $this->img_h = imagesy($this->img_r);
}

function resize($largestSide = 100) {
    $width     = imagesx($this->img_r);
    $height    = imagesy($this->img_r);
    $newWidth  = 0;
    $newHeight = 0;

    if ($width > $height) {
        $newWidth  = $largestSide;
        $newHeight = $height * ($newWidth / $width);
    } else {
        $newHeight = $largestSide;
        $newWidth  = $width * ($newHeight / $height);
    }

    $this->dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor($newWidth, $newHeight);
    imagecopyresampled($this->dst_r, $this->img_r, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);
    $this->img_r = $this->dst_r;
    $this->img_h = $newHeight;
    $this->img_w = $newWidth;
}

function createFile($output_filename = null) {
    if ($this->ext == "JPG" OR $this->ext == "JPEG") {
        imageJPEG($this->dst_r, $this->uploaddir . $output_filename . '.' . $this->ext, $this->quality);
    } elseif ($this->ext == "PNG") {
        imagePNG($this->dst_r, $this->uploaddir . $output_filename . '.' . $this->ext);
    } elseif ($this->ext == "GIF") {
        imageGIF($this->dst_r, $this->uploaddir . $output_filename . '.' . $this->ext);
    }
    $this->output = $this->uploaddir . $output_filename . '.' . $this->ext;
}

function setUploadDir($dirname) {
    $this->uploaddir = $dirname;
}

function flush() {
    $tempFile   = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
    $targetFile = str_replace('//', '/', $targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    imagedestroy($this->dst_r);
    unlink($targetFile);
    imagedestroy($this->img_r);
}

if (!empty($_FILES)) { 
    $tempFile   = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
    $targetFile = str_replace('//', '/', $targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);

    $image = new Image();
    $image->setFile($targetFile);
    $image->setUploadDir($targetPath);
    $image->resize(800);
    $image->createFile($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
    $image->flush();
}
```

This still will not work because you're calling these methods as though they're member functions of an `Image` object which isn't defined anywhere. Take a look at [Objects and Classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) in the PHP manual.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, but this is supposed to not add the extension after the files?

Comment: @Al12 This is all your code - I just cleaned it up a bit. Make sure that you're defining an `Image` object as well (you're not doing that here).

Comment: Hey thanks...well, the code works as it is in fact.. i mean what i needed is just that when the new image is created not to take any extension as it oes for the moment.. but anyways i'm going to take a look again